# How public members of a class causes havoc in java?

Tags: java, class, public

How public members of a class causes havoc in java? Can someone please explain with example? I tried to create such situation but couldn't succeed. I simply found them equivalent to 'protected' access modifier.

Comment: It is not necessary to declare all the member variables private or public, it depends upon the application. Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57491/do-all-your-variables-need-to-be-declared-private

Comment: You should also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows invalid values, breaking encapsulation.

```
public class Clock {
    public int hours;
    public int minutes;
}
```

Then, in unrelated code...

```
Clock clock = new Clock();
clock.hours = 42;
clock.minutes = 99;
```

Having them private with setter and getter methods allows encapsulation to enforce proper values.

```
public class Clock {
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    public void setHours(int hours) {
        if (hours < 0 || hours > 23) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad range");
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    // Likewise for "setMinutes" method.
}
```

Here's a [tutorial page on encapsulation in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) on encapsulation's benefits.  Quoting:

> - The fields of a class can be made read-only or write-only.
> - A class can have total control over what is stored in its fields.
> - The users of a class do not know how the class stores its data. A
>     class can change the data type of a field, and users of the class do
>     not need to change any of their code.

Comment: Wouldn't this happen with protected access modifier?

Comment: @dganesh2002 Yes, but only if you hate yourself so much. Protected fields aren't accessible from outside the boundaries of a package, meaning that no outside agent can tamper the inner gears of your class.

Comment: Only in subclasses, which already have the responsibility of maintaining its superclass's contract.

Answer (score 0):

**I believe it all depends on the application/program that you design.**

Declaring the members as private definitely does have advantages.

```
But on the other hand,
```

> If you design say a Point Class, which the users would be inheriting
>   and using it to draw various shapes, square, rectangle, circle, you
>   might think of keeping the memebers x, y, z as public.

### Example:

```
class Point{

    public double x = 0.0;
    public double y = 0.0;
    public double z = 0.0;

}
```

The advantage here would be; the classes Rectangle, Square, can access the points directly

say;

```
class Square extends Point{

    private Point p;

    p.x = 4.0;
    p.y = 10.0;
    p.z = 0;

    // Instead of using double x = p.getX(); double p.setX(5.0);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Read the below articles; it should help you.

1. [Source 1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57491/do-all-your-variables-need-to-be-declared-private)
2. [Source 2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html)
3. [Source 3](http://typicalprogrammer.com/?p=23)